# To get the field name in an entity using column name

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Is there any way to get the field name in an entity using column name.

```
@Table(name = "ESTABLISHMENT")
public class Establishment implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "EST_CODE")
    private Long code;


    @Column(name = "W_CODE")
    private Long wCode;

}
```

//service

I have W_CODE name is there any way to get the field name in the entity. Here its wCode.
I want to use that to create a custom JPQL query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse the column annotations:

```
for (Field field : entity.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
   Column column = field.getAnnotation(Column.class);
   if (column != null) {
      columnNames.add(column.name());
   }
}
```

Comment: If you dig more on Field object, you will get many other things to play like fields name, annotations present and their values and etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Column name list using your Entity or Model. What we need is `@Column`, which should be used in your Entity. You will get all the details which you have specified in `@Column`. All the parameters are *optional*, although it is good to define all.

> @Column(name, columnDefinition, insertable, length, nullable,
>   precision, scale, table, unique, updatable)

We can get all fields declared in Entity by `User.class.getDeclaredFields()` *( in general ModelName.class.getDeclaredFields())*. After getting all feilds we can get particular Column using `field.getAnnotation(Column.class)` we can also get all the details specified in `@Column` as below

```
Columns: @javax.persistence.Column(nullable=false, precision=2, unique=true, name=id, length=2, scale=1, updatable=false, columnDefinition=, table=, insertable=true)
Columns: @javax.persistence.Column(nullable=true, precision=0, unique=false, name=client_id, length=255, scale=0, updatable=true, columnDefinition=, table=, insertable=true)
Columns: @javax.persistence.Column(nullable=true, precision=0, unique=false, name=firstname, length=255, scale=0, updatable=true, columnDefinition=, table=, insertable=true)
Columns: @javax.persistence.Column(nullable=true, precision=0, unique=false, name=lastname, length=255, scale=0, updatable=true, columnDefinition=, table=, insertable=true)
```

*create endPoint or method as per requirement*

```
@GetMapping(value= "/columns/name")
    public List<String> tableColumnsName()
    {   
        List<String> Columns = new ArrayList<String>();
        Field[] fields = User.class.getDeclaredFields();

        for (Field field : fields) {
            Column col = field.getAnnotation(Column.class);
            if (col != null) {
                Columns.add(col.name());
                System.out.println("Columns: "+col);
            }
         }
          return Columns;   
    }
```

Comment: No one asked or required an endpoint here, so please remove. Secondly, name transformation may happen, i.e. a column without an explicit name like "FooBar" ends up in a column name "FOO_BAR" (or may end up).